# Keep running a script via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, shell-script, scripting, remote

`ssh` can use to run remote commands.

```
ssh me@server.com 'long-script.sh'
```

I run a long script that will take a lot of time, but I want to close my computer and keep running the script in the remote server. I know how to achieve this with [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), but I need do it via `ssh`.

Can I do that without interrupting my script?

Comment: What's wrong with starting screen on the remote server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use "nohup" to run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty:

```
nohup your_command &
```

and to run a command via ssh, without first logging into the remote machine:

```
ssh user_name@machine_address "nohup your_script.sh" &
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ ssh me@server.com screen -dm long-script.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

`ssh user@server "nohup script.sh >/var/log/output.log 2>&1 &"`

That should run the remote command without leaving a running ssh process on your client.