# Can a shell script running in a ssh continue to run if the SSH instance closes?

Tags: ssh, remote, logout

I'm trying to write a shell script that does a lengthy batch job on a remote server. I'll be running the script over SSH.

The thing is, I intend to start the script in the evening and collect the results the next morning; I'd prefer not to have my local computer have to run all night, as it's not needed as part of the batch process. As such, is there a way I can close the SSH connection and still have the shell script continue to run on the remote server?

Comment: You can run the script within `tmux` or `screen` and reconnect later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you start the script to run in the background, it will continue to run.  Alternately, you can start the script by using the command on command-line.  For example, you can say:

```
ssh hostname -l loginname command
```

and that will work.

Comment: *"Yes, if you start the script to run in the background, it will continue to run."* -> Not if there's a process in there that closes automatically when it finds stdin closed.  That's the major reason `nohup` exists, I think.

Comment: It certainly continued to run for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this would be to use nohup. Here is an example:

```
nohup your_prog.sh &
```

This will run the program called `your_prog.sh` in the background with `&` and redirect all the outputs to a file called `nohup.out`.

Now, you can monitor the output of the program running in the background by using a command like:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

The program that is started with the `nohup` command will continue to run until terminated by a reboot or an explicit `kill` command (or until your program exits).

Comment: This question was asked and answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29470/keep-running-a-script-via-ssh?rq=1)