# Running a "scheduled"/delayed script as sudo on server, via ssh - and right before ssh exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

This would have probably been answered by [Keep running a script via ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29470/keep-running-a-script-via-ssh), if I didn't have to run a command as superuser. Let me try with an example: say on my server, I have this script as `~/testsleep.sh`, which is also `chmod +x`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logger Pre sleep: "$USER" / "$USERNAME" / "$1"

sleep 5

logger Post sleep: "$USER" / "$USERNAME" / "$1"
```

I want to have `logger` log to `/var/log/syslog`, since via `ssh` I'm likely to lose stdout/stderr.

Say I run this on my local PC, logged in via `ssh` to the remote server:

```
server$ readlink -f ~/testsleep.sh 
/home/user/testsleep.sh

server$ $ ls -la testsleep.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 126 2015-02-05 13:35 testsleep.sh

server$ sudo /home/user/testsleep.sh some_argument
sudo: unable to execute /home/user/testsleep.sh: No such file or directory
```

The first problem is that I cannot run the script directly with `sudo`, even if it is executable; I think this has to do with "*your current shell is running under your regular user ID ... and there is no way to grant it root access*" [Execute a shell script in current shell with sudo permission - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809614/execute-a-shell-script-in-current-shell-with-sudo-permission)

Ok, fine, I'll run `sudo bash` - this looks more like it:

```
server$ sudo bash /home/user/testsleep.sh some_argument

server$ tail -2 /var/log/syslog
Feb  5 13:40:48 user user: Pre sleep: root / root / some_argument
Feb  5 13:40:53 user user: Post sleep: root / root / some_argument
```

So, apparently the script does log in `syslog`, and sees `root` as `$USER`; as intended. So far, so good.

Now, I'd like to run this script as a process on the server, right before I exit my `ssh` terminal session. I guess I'd do this:

```
server$ sudo bash /home/user/testsleep.sh from_end & exit
[1] 6293
logout
Connection to 127.1.100.99 closed.
local$
```

If I log back in into the server, and check `syslog` again, I can see that there is no log from this last, "exiting" invocation:

```
# this `grep` will print the filename, if file doesn't contain the match:

server$ grep --files-without-match 'from_end' /var/log/syslog
/var/log/syslog
server$ tail -2 /var/log/syslog
Feb  5 13:40:48 mypc user: Pre sleep: root / root / some_argument
Feb  5 13:40:53 mypc user: Post sleep: root / root / some_argument
```

So, my question is - how can I run this script as a process, under sudo on the server - but invoked from an `ssh` shell, and right before exiting it; so that it runs (in this case, confirmed by writing to the `syslog`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `disown` the job so it doesn't get killed when the connection is "hung up":

```
sudo bash /home/user/testsleep.sh from_end & sleep 1; disown -h; exit
```

The `sleep 1` is in there to reduce the race between the background job starting and the shell exiting. If you can avoid having to do everything in a single line you'll get better results separating the two sets of commands:

```
sudo bash /home/user/testsleep.sh from_end &
disown -h; exit
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, @StephenKitt, that seems to work great! Just a note: if I forget to do say `sudo ls` before I execute the command, so that my password is asked for and temporarily remembered, then I might get `[1]+  Stopped                 sudo bash /home/user/testsleep.sh from_end ; logout ; There are stopped jobs.`, so I had to do `fg` until I saw and answered the password prompt. Btw, in syslog I get `mypc user: Pre sleep: root...`but `mypc logger: Post sleep: root...` - any idea why "pre sleep" has `user` and "post sleep" has `logger` as username?

Comment: The `sudo` prompt is normal if that execution needs a password. At least you get a chance to fix the problem ;-). As to `logger` appearing in the log instead of `user`, I can hazard a guess but I'd rather check.